# Implementing Live Background

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to implement this live background into my webpage but right now only part of it shows up in like the top side of the page and it messes up with the rest of the divs. For my HTML I have all my body contents inside one big div and the first part of the div is the html for the live background. I'm trying to have it so it's displayed throughout the body but with a z index of -1. I'm not sure how to adjust the css for that, I can fix the other elements getting messed up but I want the background to be throughout the body. 
EDIT: Here's a link to the website rn: http://ishabulhaque.com/ 
HTML

```css
   #particle{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     z-index: -1; 
      }
```

```html
> <div id = "particle">

<div id="particles-background" class="vertical-centered-box"></div>
     <div id="particles-foreground" class="vertical-centered-box"></div>
 
     <div class="vertical-centered-box">
       <div class="content">
         <div class="loader-circle"></div>
         <div class="loader-line-mask">
           <div class="loader-line"></div>
         </div>
         <svg width="36px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 36 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
           <path d="M8.98885921,23.8523026 C8.8942483,23.9435442 8.76801031,24 8.62933774,24 L2.03198365,24 C1.73814918,24 1.5,23.7482301 1.5,23.4380086 C1.5,23.2831829 1.55946972,23.1428989 1.65570253,23.0416777 L13.2166154,12.4291351 C13.3325814,12.3262031 13.4061076,12.1719477 13.4061076,11.999444 C13.4061076,11.8363496 13.3401502,11.6897927 13.2352673,11.587431 L1.68841087,0.990000249 C1.57298556,0.88706828 1.5,0.733668282 1.5,0.561734827
 C1.5,0.251798399 1.73814918,2.85130108e-05 2.03198365,2.85130108e-05
 L8.62933774,2.85130108e-05 C8.76855094,2.85130108e-05
 8.89532956,0.0561991444 8.98994048,0.148296169 L21.4358709,11.5757407 C21.548593,11.6783875 21.6196864,11.8297916 21.6196864,11.999444
 C21.6196864,12.1693815 21.5483227,12.3219261 21.4350599,12.4251432
 L8.98885921,23.8523026 Z M26.5774333,23.8384453 L20.1765996,17.9616286
 C20.060093,17.8578413 19.9865669,17.703871 19.9865669,17.5310822
 C19.9865669,17.3859509 20.0390083,17.2536506 20.1246988,17.153855
 L23.4190508,14.1291948 C23.5163648,14.0165684 23.6569296,13.945571
 23.8131728,13.945571 C23.9602252,13.945571 24.0929508,14.0082997 24.1894539,14.1092357 L33.861933,22.9913237 C33.9892522,23.0939706 34.0714286,23.2559245 34.0714286,23.4381226 C34.0714286,23.748059 33.8332794,23.9998289 33.5394449,23.9998289 L26.9504707,23.9998289 C26.8053105,23.9998289 26.6733958,23.9382408 26.5774333,23.8384453 Z
 M26.5774333,0.161098511 C26.6733958,0.0615881034 26.8053105,0
 26.9504707,0 L33.5394449,0 C33.8332794,0 34.0714286,0.251769886 34.0714286,0.561706314 C34.0714286,0.743904453 33.9892522,0.905573224 33.861933,1.00822006 L24.1894539,9.89030807 C24.0929508,9.99152926 23.9602252,10.0542579 23.8131728,10.0542579 C23.6569296,10.0542579 23.5163648,9.98354562 23.4190508,9.87063409 L20.1246988,6.8459739 C20.0390083,6.74617837 19.9865669,6.613878 19.9865669,6.46874677
 C19.9865669,6.29624305 20.060093,6.14198767 20.1765996,6.03848544
 L26.5774333,0.161098511 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
         </svg>
       </div> </div></div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything but a white snippet box after pushing "Run code snippet"

Comment: You have two divs with the same ID, and there's no #particle (an element with ID particle) in the snippet

Comment: I added the div, I didn't originally add it in the original post

Comment: Just white background with `>`.

Comment: Try to add it in a working snippet - that way you’ll see how your code looks like to everybody else.

Comment: added a link to the website, that might be more helpful, thanks everyone